# Is there way to prove that non-abelian group of order $p^3$ has non-trivial center using $G/Z(G) \cong Inn(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I know that $|Z(G)| \neq p^2$ or $p^3$ due to contradictions with $G$ being non-abelian.
Therefore, the remaining possibilities are $1$ or $p$. I aim to prove $∣Z(G)∣=p$ without resorting to the class equation, for example, by using the theorem $G/Z(G) \cong Inn(G)$.

I took a look over books as Contemporary abstract algebra by Joseph Galian or Abstract Algebra by Foot and Dummit to search for theorems concerning $Inn(G)$ that would help but I didn't find.

I just want hints because I love learning by doing efforts.

Comment: Are you familiar with "every p group of order > 1 has a non-trivial center"?

Comment: @agent_cracker103:  Yes I know, but I am asking about idea of proving it other than using class equation, I want to try proving it using $Inn(G)$.

Comment: There's a way to use the class equation in this case. I mean using Abstract Algebra 01, you can prove that equation for this special case. I can give you hints if you want.

Comment: @Ash   Give me hint, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: @agent_cracker103  $Inn(G) \cong Z_{p} \oplus Z_{p}$ since it cannot be cyclic, because that would mean that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar So Let's say $x\sim y$ iff $x$ is conjugate to $y$. Prove that this is an equivalence relation. Then prove that for any $x\in G$, size of the equivalence class containing $x$, equals $|G:C_G(x)|$. Please let me know when you prove all these, they can all be proved using Abstract Algebra 1.

Comment: @Ash    Ok, thank you, I will do it now, and tell you when I finish proving.

Comment: @Ash: I have finished the first hint, by proving what you have asked me to prove.

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar Now which elements are in class of order $1$? Now on the contrary assume that $Z(G)=1$, knowing the fact that $G$ is a $p$-group, try to reach a contradiction using the fact that $|G|=\sum|cl(x_i)|$ where $x_i$‘s are class representatives. Have this $|cl(x)|=|G:C_G(x)|$ in your mind.

Comment: There is an incredibly useful lemma for this and many many other things related to finite $p$-groups: When a $p$-group $P$ acts on a set $X$, then
\begin{equation*}
|X^P|\equiv |X|\pmod{p}
\end{equation*}
where $X^P$ is the subset of fixed points. This is easy to prove, since the orbit-stabilizer theorem says every orbit of size $>1$ must have size divisible by $p$. You could use this lemma with $P=G$ acting on $X=G$ by conjugation.

Comment: @Ash I put solution using your hints, please, give your opinion when you have time.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks for your help, I will try your idea in future.

Answer (score 0):

Solving using hints of @Ash:
(But my original question is about whether it is possible to try calculate $Inn(G)$ and by it showing that $|Z(G)|$ must be $p$).

Define the equivalence relation:

$x \sim y$ iff  there exists $g \in G: x=gyg^{-1}$.

proof:

Reflexive: $x \sim x$ because $x=exe^{-1}$.

Symmetric: Assume $x \sim y \rightarrow \exists g: x=gyg^{-1} \rightarrow y=g^{-1}x(g^{-1})^{-1} \rightarrow y \sim x$.

Transitive: Assume $x \sim y $ and $y \sim z \rightarrow \exists g_{1},g_{2}: x=g_{1}yg_{1}^{-1}$ and $y=g_{2}zg_{2}^{-1} \rightarrow x=(g_{1}g_{2})z(g_{1}g_{2})^{-1} \rightarrow x \sim z $.

Now, $cl(x)= \{y: \exists g: x=gyg^{-1} \}=\{y: \exists g: xg=gy \}$.

For $m \in cl(x)$:

If $m=x$, then $x \sim x$ because $x=gxg^{-1} \forall g \in C_{G}(x)$.

If $m \neq x$, then $x \sim m$ because $x=gmg^{-1} \forall g $ in the coset $ gC_{G}(x)$.

Thus, number of conjugates of x which is $|cl(x)|$ equals number of cosets of $C_{G}(x)$ which is $|[G:C_{G}(x)]|$.

Let $|G|=p^n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (I choose to generalize the problem instead of p^3)

Now, assume $|Z(G)|=1$.

Recall that: $Z(G)= \bigcap_{x \in G} (C_{G}(x))= \{e \}$ because $|Z(G)|=1$.

$|G|= \sum |cl(x_{i})|$.

If $x_{i}=e$, then $|cl(x)|=|cl(e)|=1$

So, $|G|=p^n=1+\sum cl(x_{i})$. where $x_{i} \neq e$.

Thus: $p^n-1=\sum cl(x_{i})$. where $x_{i} \neq e$

$|x_{i}|=p^{j} $ for some $1 \leq j \leq n-1$ (note $j \neq n$ becuase $G$ is non-cyclic).

Now:$p$ divides $|x_{i}|$ divides $|C_{G}(x_{i})| < p^n$, by Lagrange's Theorem.

We have $p$ divides $\sum cl(x_{i})$. where $x_{i} \neq e$, so $p$ divides $p^{n}-1$ which is contradiction.

Comment: @Ash: Give your opinion about the solution.

Comment: Nice job. Now we get that $Z(G)>1$, and as you mentioned $|Z(P)|\notin \{p^2,p^3\}$, which means $Z(p)\cong C_p$. So that's about it. The class equation is nothing more than what you did here with conjugacy classes (those equivalence classes are called conjugacy classes.). If you got time just take a quick look at groups actions. You can use "A Course on Group Theory" by John S. Rose, and for more motivation brother, you've just proved Theorem 4.28 of that book. Sorry I wasn't notified for this answer.